# Default in unspecified parameter in Meteor helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I would like to set a default value for a parameter when it is not specified within the template calling it, however Spacebars always passes a "Spacebars.ks" object in.

For instance If I call a helper in my template:

```
{{formatDate creation_date}}
```

And the helper looks something like this:

```
Template.registerHelper( "formatDate", function( date, format ) {
    if( format === undefined ) {
        format = "day month year";
    }
    // format date...
});
```

the "format" parameter is always set to the object "Spacebars.ks" it is never undefined.

What is the correct way to handle this in Meteor?

Comment: Hi, check Akshats answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755891/meteor-what-is-spacebars-kw-hash-object#answer-27756461